# How can you override an existing Gradle plugin from a local repository?

Tags: java, javafx, gradle, java-8, jacoco

I am building an application using Gradle, JDK 8, Java FX, and Test FX. I need to be on JDK 8 for our application to work on all platforms with our tech stack. My problem is that I am unable to get code coverage into our build. I found this link...

https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/74

...and using the Jacoco preview build at the top, I was able to replace my intellij JARs and successfully run my tests and get the coverage. However, I am having trouble putting this into my build.gradle. From what I can tell, I need to add a local repository in my build script...

```
...
apply plugin: "jacoco"
...
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Local Repo
        // MVN Repo(s)
    }
    dependencies {
        // Classpaths
    }
}
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.6.4.201311160552" // I need this specific version, which isn't on a MVN repo
}
```

...I tried to add my local repo several ways including...

- flatDir(dirs: "lib")
- flatDir dirs: "${projectDir}/lib"
- maven { url uri("lib") }
- one or two other ways I forget

...my lib folder contains the exact contents, unchanged, from the preview build zip's lib folder in the link above. It doesn't seem like gradle is having a problem locating the local repo, but it is having trouble finding the JAR. I assume there is something wrong with the way I am naming it or the way that it is "packaged". I have tried modifying the JAR names but I keep getting the error...

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'myProject'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find :org.jacoco.agent:.
>    Required by:
>        :myProject:unspecified
>   
>   ...any ideas why my JAR is not being found? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Answering" my own question, despite the fact that I still haven't quite figured it out. Anyways, here are two links I found that seem to solve my problem...

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/jacocotestreport_is_skipping

...following some of these instructions allow my tests to run, but I am still not able to run "gradle jacocoTestReport" without it failing.

***UPDATE***

OKAY! I figured it out, the link above did help me figure it out. My problem was with the asm-all JAR, since there were several, I did not know which one to use. In order to get jacoco working with Java 1.8, you do not need to specify the toolVersion property. All you need to do is add the following to your dependencies block (not the buildscript block, the code block)...

jacocoAgent files(
     "$projectDir/lib/org.jacoco.agent-0.6.4.201311160552.jar")

jacocoAnt files(
    "$projectDir/lib/org.jacoco.ant-0.6.4.201311160552.jar", 
    "$projectDir/lib/org.jacoco.core-0.6.4.201311160552.jar", 
    "$projectDir/lib/org.jacoco.report-0.6.4.201311160552.jar", 
    "$projectDir/lib/asm-all-5.0_BETA.jar")

...where the asm-all-5.0_BETA.jar is taken from the org.ow2.asm group found at...

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm-all/5.0_BETA

...hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

for reference, latest jacoco libs are changed so i'm sharing the following snippet:

```
dependencies{
    jacocoAgent files("$rootProject.projectDir/lib/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.3.201904130250.jar")
    jacocoAnt files("$rootProject.projectDir/lib/org.jacoco.ant-0.8.3.201904130250.jar",
            "$rootProject.projectDir/lib/org.jacoco.core-0.8.3.201904130250.jar",
            "$rootProject.projectDir/lib/org.jacoco.report-0.8.3.201904130250.jar",
            "$rootProject.projectDir/lib/asm-7.0.jar",
            "$rootProject.projectDir/lib/asm-tree-7.0.jar",
            "$rootProject.projectDir/lib/asm-commons-7.0.jar"
            )
}
```